# NSTimer Consume battery consumuntation of iOS device or not

Tags: ios, iphone, ios7, ios6, nstimer

In app when using NSTimer then this timer is consume battery of iOS device..?

We are schedule this NSTimer for every 30 SEC in app whether app in foreground or background.

In this timer we just check internet availability by sending request to host.

Comment: Every running code consume battery.

Comment: Right,but timer more consume then other running code..?

Answer (score 0):

You can use this nice and simple block based, drop dead Reachability class to get notified whenever there is any change in network availability.

https://github.com/tonymillion/Reachability

**Do not** use a Timer to get notified for network connection changes.

Comment: We are using this but it is available for WiFi only when mobile packdata has not available for mobile then this is not use...  So we are use timer for check mobile packdata is available or not...

Comment: // Tell the reachability that we WANT to be reachable on 3G/EDGE/CDMA
reach.reachableOnWWAN = YES;

Comment: We are also using SimplePingHelper class for this.but it is only check for WiFi only using ping to host Not for mobile packet data.